# ExpressionEngine and WorkflowMax

Tags: solspace-freeform, campaignmonitor

I am looking to integrate EE with the WorkflowMax (SAS project management software, via their API). The idea was to collect leads directly into Workflow max when someone requests a callback, as this is the CRM for the business.

I want to use FreeFormPro to setup these enquiry forms etc. Should I do this first, and fine tune all our forms, then get the plugin developed?

I was also planning on using Freeform to add people to our CampaignMonitor mailing list, for those who arent enquiring but just want to get the newsletter (people we no very little about).

Will I still be able to use FreeFormPro once we connect to Workflowmax- not sure how all this works together. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should approach a developer and see how they want to go about the integration. It depends on many things, such as the Workflowmax API etc.

However, I would say it is probably possible to collect responses using Freeform, then use one of their extension hooks to submit this to Workflowmax. The other option would be for your developer to create a plugin which submits the data directly to workflowmax, without going through Freeform - there are pros and cons to each strategy.